# Annihilation of some Kähler differential.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

It is mentioned in the proof of
Proposition 2.(2) of this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X86901058) that if $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$ and
$$ \sum_{\sigma\neq 0}a_1^{\sigma(1)}\cdots a_i^{\sigma(i)}z_{\sigma}^p=x^p $$
where $a_i,x,z_{\sigma}\in K$ (with $x,z_{\sigma}$ not all $0$) and $\sigma$ runs through the set of maps $\{1,\ldots,i\}\longrightarrow\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ that are not identically $0$, then one has
$$ \frac{da_1}{a_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\frac{da_i}{a_i}=0 $$
in the module of absolue Kähler differentials $\Omega_{K/\mathbb{Z}}^i$ though I can't see why. I want to use the fact that, $K$ being of characteristic $p$, $d(x^p)=0$ but I don't really know how to link the LHS with the differential above.

Comment: What kinds of functoriality do you have for the dlog map? It feels like a Frobenius compatibility might give this vanishing. Also, is there a simpler way to see this for Pfister forms?